# remove dash in phone number within razor

Tags: javascript, razor

I need to call a JavaScript method and am using razor to print the parameters...

```
getNumber(@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.phone1)">
```

However, JavaScript treats a dash in the phone number as a subtraction operator.

I tried a regular expression to remove the dash, but I can't figure out the right syntax. This still performs the subtraction operation and gives me the JavaScript error [subtration result].replace is not a function

```
getNumber((@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.phone1)).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))">
```

Comment: Have you actually tried converting the model.phone1 to the string with casting? `String(model.phone1)`?

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the dash as much as you need to enclose the number in quotes so it gets treated as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat phone numbers as strings, to do this make sure JavaScript also knows the number is a string by enclosing it in quotes:

```
getNumber('@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.phone1')
```

This should get rendered something like this:

```
getNumber('1-800-CALL-ME')
```

Comment: Yes, that's got it. I tried that and it wouldn't run, but I must have gotten the syntax wrong.